# Can't query the reminders in a calendar from ekstore

Tags: ios, calendar, ios6, reminders, ekeventkit

I'm trying to get a list of reminders from a calendar but I'm keep getting an error. I can do a similar thing with calendar events but when i try and amend it for reminders i run into problems.
This code fails on the first line to do with EKEntityMaskReminder

```
   _store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskReminder];
        EKCalendar *calendar = [_store calendarWithIdentifier:[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"cal_id"]];
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:calendar];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [_store predicateForRemindersInCalendars:calendarArray];
    _eventsList = [_store fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:nil];
```

The error message is:

> -[EKEventStore initWithAccessToEntityTypes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157660

If i change the store thus:

```
_store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

then it fails with:

> ```
> '-[EKEventStore predicateForRemindersInCalendars:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165c20'
> ```

I am able to create a reminder if i set the store as:

```
_store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

and it shows in the reminders app.

Does anyone know why i can't query these reminders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the selectors you're getting errors on have availability starting with iOS 6.  If you're trying to run your program against something other than the beta OS/libraries, it's going to fail.

(It's extremely odd that `initWithAccessToEntityTypes` is **recommended** in iOS 5.1 documentation, though without a method description.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that's the reason. I just couldn't understand what it could be.

Comment: I assume you're building against iOS 6, otherwise the compiler should have complained before you ever got that far.